# Saving JTable values to array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I wrote the self contained example below and I have it working pretty much the way I want except for one thing.  Currently, if the user clicks an Ellipse2D it will highlight a cell in the JTable and allow them to input strings.  The problem is that when you close the program it doesn't save the values to Object[][] data.

How do I save the input to Object[][] data so that the next time I run the application it is present?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SelfContainedExample extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private Map<Ellipse2D.Double, Point> shapesMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Ellipse2D.Double[] ellipses = new Ellipse2D.Double[] {
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 100, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(175, 100, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(300, 100, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 160, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(175, 160, 30, 30),
                                          new Ellipse2D.Double(300, 160, 30, 30)};

    static Object[][] data = {{"1_1", "1_2", "1_3"},
                              {"2_1", "2_2", "2_3"},
                              {"3_1", "2_2", "2_3"},
                              {"4_1", "2_2", "2_3"},
                              {"5_1", "2_2", "2_3"},
                              {"6_1", "2_2", "2_3"}};

    static Object[] columnNames = {"1", "2", "3"};
    static JTable jtable = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    public SelfContainedExample() {

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        for (Ellipse2D.Double ellipse : ellipses) {

            shapesMap.put(ellipse, new Point(row, column));
            row++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                             RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
            g2d.fill(ellipse);
        }

        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
            g2d.draw(ellipse);
        }

        addMouseListener(this);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtable);

        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(385, 119));

        tablePanel.add(jScrollPane);
        tablePanel.setSize(200, 200);

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new SelfContainedExample(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        for (Ellipse2D.Double ellipse : ellipses) {
            if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                jtable.requestFocusInWindow();
                Point p = shapesMap.get(ellipse);
                jtable.editCellAt(p.x, p.y);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JTables or Swing  and all to do with Java persistence of data, and only this. Look this up and you'll find a wealth of possible solutions including serialization, writing to a file, database...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks.

Comment: Note, I see a **big** problem in your code where you appear to be adding a MouseListener within your paintComponent method -- **NEVER** do this, not unless you want the GUI to have many, many mouse listeners added uncontrollably.

Comment: The only Swing-related issues in my mind will revolve around events -- what event should trigger the data being saved? A save button ActionListener? A window closing event? A Timer to intermittently save data as the program runs? The other Swing related issue is taking care that all file I/O be done on a thread background to the Swing event thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I actually like the idea of a timer intermittently saving the data.  This is the approach I will pursue.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so now I'm wondering how to safely create  a thread and dispose of it properly to take care of the i/o you mentioned.